# Spring Boot + PostgreSQL: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I don't understand why suddenly I can't save new object in my table Framework.

My entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude="frameworkSortingType")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "framework")
public class Framework {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "framework", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private FrameworkSortingType frameworkSortingType;
```

ERROR:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, 1, 1, 1, null, 2020-11-23 01:14:43.472, null, 2020-11-23 01:14:43.472, 1, 783772).
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:120)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
```

What is the problem? `ID` has to be set to NULL t save new object in table! When I want to update some row then `ID` column cannot be null... But I can't understand why suddenly I can't add new row in my table `Framework`. Recently I added only `@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude="frameworkSortingType")` because sometimes I had circular dependency with `FrameworkSortingType` table. But I don't think this change is the reason of my problem...

I'd like to add that on DEV remote server it works, Framework is old table... the error occurs locally on my computer...

Answer (score 0):

You have annotated id field with @Id, that means now  id is PRIMARY key so it will be not null.

```
GenerationType.AUTO
```

The GenerationType.AUTO indicates that the persistence provider should select an appropriate strategy based on the specified database dialect. The AUTO will automatically set the generated values. It is the default GenerationType. If no strategy is defined, it will consider AUTO by default. All the databases support this strategy.

Here I can see you are trying to save when id =null that you can not do. So do not assign any value to id field. Spring-boot will take care everything.

Answer (score 0):

@GeneratedValue annotation is used along with @Id annotation to automatically generate unique values for primary key columns within the database tables. When we apply @GeneratedValue annotation to our primary key field or property. It will instruct hibernate to automatically generate a unique value for that field during the process of persisting the entity into the database.

Are you trying to insert data into the table along with id value? If yes then, @GeneratedValue annotation is not required.